# Cake php nested table alias query

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, nested, subquery

For this query :-

```
SELECT `user_name` 
FROM `users`  
where `department` = (SELECT `department` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = 'xyz')
```

I was able to do it from buildstatement

For ex:-

```
$subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
                                    array(
                                        'fields'     => array('Users.department'),
                                        'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->Users),
                                        'alias'      => 'Users',
                                        'limit'      => null,
                                        'offset'     => null,
                                        'joins'      => array(),
                                        'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
                                        'order'      => null,
                                        'group'      => null
                                    ),
                                    $this->Users
                                );
$subQuery = 'Users.department = (' . $subQuery . ') ';

    $subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);

    $conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;

$this->Paginator->settings =    $conditions ;
```

As query was build with cake php convention I was able to use cake php pagination directly.

Now I am trying to build below query but I am not getting that

```
SELECT count(Users.department) FROM (SELECT `department` FROM `users`) AS `Users`   WHERE 1 = 1
```

I have tried in this manner

```
$subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
                                    array(
                                        'fields'     => array('count(Users.department)'),
                                        'table'      => "(SELECT `department` FROM `users`)",
                                        'alias'      => 'Users',
                                        'limit'      => null,
                                        'offset'     => null,
                                        'joins'      => array(),
                                       /* 'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,*/
                                        'order'      => null,
                                        'group'      => null
                                    ),
                                    $this->Users
                                );
```

Please help me on this.
It will help me to use cake php pagination for all other nested queries.

Comment: any suggestions on this will be helpfull

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? You should read up on retrieving data for a Model in CakePHP.